# If $Pr(A)+Pr(B) > 1$ then what is the maximum and minimum value for $Pr(A\cap B)$?

Tags: probability

If $Pr(A)+Pr(B) > 1$ then what is the maximum and minimum value for $Pr(A\cap B)$?

I guess that the minimum should be when $Pr(A \cup B) = 1$ because then you have that $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A \cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-1$ but I don't really know what to do for the maximum. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well if $A=B$ and $Pr(A)=1$, then $Pr(A)+Pr(B)=2$ and $Pr(A\cap B)=1$ isn't it?

Comment: I'd say maximum $1$, minimum doesn't exist (can take any value $0<p\le 1$).

Comment: Take the space $[0,1]$ with uniform probability, then $A=B=[0,1]$ gives $P(A\cap B) = 1$ and if $\epsilon>0$ then $A=[0,{1 \over 2}+ \epsilon], B=[{1 \over 2},1]$, then $P(A \cap B) = \epsilon$. Hence the $\inf$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=B$ and $Pr(A)=1$, then $Pr(A)+Pr(B)=2$ and $Pr(A\cap B)=1$ so the maximum is $1$.

Regarding the minimum, let $t\in[0,1]$ and for $k\geq 1$, let $A_k,B_k$ be the events respectively defined as $t\in [0,\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{k}]$ and $t\in [\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{k},1]$, then $Pr(A_k)+Pr(B_k)=1+2/k$ for all $k\geq 0$ and so the minimum is, de facto an infimum, and equals $0$ by letting $k\to \infty$.